# How to fetch all images from a url in PHP?

Tags: php

I have got a PHP code to get all images in a URL. It will display the URL of the image. But there are some problems with the URL of the image obtained.

1: If the images are hosted in the root directory, it will not show the domain. For example, if the given URL is www.google.com, the URL of the image obtained is

"/logos/doodles/2014/womens-day-2014-6253511574552576.3-hp.png"

and what I need is

"www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/womens-day-2014-6253511574552576.3-hp.png"

2: The URL obtained is always between " ". How can I remove it??

Here the PHP code

```
<?php
$url_image = $_GET['url'];
$homepage = file_get_contents($url_image);
preg_match_all("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $val) {
echo $val[2];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe the parse_url function can help you here, it is described here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php , maybe use it to split your $url_image and "combine" it with your image path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$url_image = $_GET['url'];
$homepage = file_get_contents($url_image);
preg_match_all("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $val) {

    $pos = strpos($val[2],"/"); 
    $link = substr($val[2],1,-1);
    if($pos == 1)
        echo "http://domain.com" . $link;
    else
        echo $link;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. I made some modifications and got the right thing. thanks a lot

here is the modified code



<?php
$url_image = $_GET['url'];
$homepage = file_get_contents($url_image);
preg_match_all("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $val) {

     $pos = strpos($val[2],"/"); 
    if($pos == 1)
 {
 
  $link = substr($val[2],2,-1);
        echo  $url_image. $link;
    }
 else
 {
  $link = substr($val[2],1,-1);
        echo $link;
  echo "<br>";
 }
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `""` using `substr($url,1,-1);`

Comment: @keepwalking wow, that really worked. Thanks a lot. I used first one